# In App purchase for first time

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in app purchase for first time. So I'm starting with a demo and my question is that if my purchase items are free and even app is free ,will it cost me anything because i don't have apple id of my own and i am using someone else's for generating certificates etc. As when i try to enable in app purchase in Xcode, its asks for apple id and password with whom the credit card is registered. The thing is that its not my account and i don't want to loose money only for demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are working in the sandbox, ie, not released, it will not cost you anything. You sign out of your personal (non-test) apple id in the Settings app and use a testing apple id you setup in iTunesConnect. If you are doing things correctly, you should not get asked for your credit card info. You will have to use a developer-registered apple id in Xcode, but this is for developer authorization, not payment.